# How to set environment variables and /etc/hosts through Vagrantfile?

Tags: docker, vagrant, docker-compose, vagrantfile, vagrant-plugin

#### Vagrant version

Vagrant 1.9.7

#### Host operating system

Darwin bogon 16.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0: Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

#### Guest operating system

distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

#### Question

How to set environment variables and /etc/hosts through **Vagrantfile**?

In docker-composer, I can set **environment** and **extra_hosts**

In vagrant, how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Vagrant manages Virtual Machines when used with Virtual Box, not a container.

If you want to have environment variable defined or specific files, the best is to use [vagrant provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/)

You can push file directly using the [file provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/file.html) or have a shell script to edit the file and add some lines.

A simple shell script to add environment variable will be

```
  config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL
    echo "export VARIABLE=VALUE" > /home/vagrant/.profile
  SHELL
```

so the variable will be available when you ssh into the machine